# C program compile and run on a system and not on another

Tags: c, gcc

I'm posting here because I couldn't find any help for this on Google.

I use Debian squeeze at uni to program some C and can ftp the content to work at home. But, I encountered this problem : a litte program I made compile with no warnings and run flawlessly at uni. But on my PC (GNU/Linux as well), it doesn't at all:
Here are the conditions:
 -using "gcc -g -o -Wextra -ansi prog prog.c"
 -works at uni, segfault here
 -valgrind gives me this:

```
==4305== Invalid read of size 1
==4305==    at 0x4EBCD60: __GI___rawmemchr (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4EA9581: _IO_str_init_static_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4E99DB6: __isoc99_vsscanf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4E99D56: __isoc99_sscanf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x400B69: main (chomp.c:108)
==4305==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4305== 
==4305== 
==4305== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4305==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==4305==    at 0x4EBCD60: __GI___rawmemchr (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4EA9581: _IO_str_init_static_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4E99DB6: __isoc99_vsscanf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x4E99D56: __isoc99_sscanf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so)
==4305==    by 0x400B69: main (chomp.c:108)
==4305==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4305==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4305==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4305==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4305==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    int** tab;
    int n;
    int m;
    }Tablette;

typedef enum{J1,J2}Joueur;

typedef struct{
    Tablette T;
    Joueur J;
    }Position;

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    }Coup;

Tablette creer_tablette(int n, int m){
    Tablette T;
    int i,j;
    T.n=n;
    T.m=m;
    T.tab = (int**) malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    if(T.tab==NULL){
        printf("Erreur\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        T.tab[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(T.tab[i]==NULL){
            printf("Erreur\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            T.tab[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
        }
return T;
}

void afficher_tablette(Tablette T){
    int i,j;
    printf("  ");
    for(j=0;j<T.m;j++)
        printf("%d ",j+1);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<T.n;i++){
        printf("%d ",i+1);
        for(j=0;j<T.m;j++){
            if(T.tab[i][j]==1)
                printf("■ ");
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void manger_tablette(Tablette *T, int x, int y){
    int i,j;
    for(i=x;i<T->n;i++){
        for(j=y;j<T->m;j++){
            T->tab[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

int est_legal(Position *pos, Coup *cp){
    if((cp->x)<0 || (cp->x)>(pos->T.m) || (cp->y)<0 || (cp->y)>(pos->T.n))
        return 0;
    if(pos->T.tab[cp->y][cp->x]==0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int fin_jeu(Position *pos, Joueur *win){
    if(pos->T.tab[0][0]==0){
        *win=pos->J;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void jouer_coup(Position *pos, Coup *cp){
    if(est_legal(pos,cp)==1)
        manger_tablette(&(pos->T),(cp->y-1),(cp->x-1));
    pos->J=(pos->J+1)%2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n,m;
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&m);
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&n);
    Tablette T=creer_tablette(n,m);
    Coup cp;
    Position pos;
    Joueur win;
    pos.T=T;
    pos.J=J1;
    while(fin_jeu(&pos,&win)!=1){
        afficher_tablette(T);
        printf("Au tour du Joueur %d\n",pos.J+1);
        printf("Entrez les coordonnées du carré que vous souhaitez manger\n");
        scanf("%d",&(cp.x));
        scanf("%d",&(cp.y));
            while(est_legal(&pos,&cp)==0){
                printf("Coordonnées non valides\n");
                scanf("%d",&(cp.x));
                scanf("%d",&(cp.y));
            }
        jouer_coup(&pos,&cp);
    }
    printf("Le Joueur %d a gagné !\n",pos.J+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Which one is line 108?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Since valgrind is complaining about a read from address 0 in `sscanf()`, it looks like you're probably running the program with too few arguments and you're accessing `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` without checking if they exist (via `argc`).

Comment: `if((cp->x)<0 || (cp->x) >= (pos->T.m) || (cp->y)<0 || (cp->y) >= (pos->T.n))`

Comment: For this line `pos.J=J1;` in `main()` . Where is `J1` declared?

Comment: Sorry for long reply, not familiar with the site.

Comment: Before the sscanf there's if(argc>1 && (strcmp(argv[1],"-h")==0 || strcmp(argv[1],"--help")==0)){
  printf("Aide d'utilisation : mangez le carré dont vous spécifiez les coordonnées durant votre tour (abscisse puis ordonnée), le joueur mangeant le carré (1,1) a perdu\n");
  exit(0);
 }

Comment: Thanks for all this help but the real problem, is that this is compiling AND running, but here, with gcc the same option, and the same source it doesn't.

Comment: Just because it compiles and runs on one platform does mean that the code is bug free. After fixing all the bugs mentioned ( bounds check, argc check, and misplaced {} ) you should recompile and rerun and if it still core dumps, repost the code. If the program is called from a script, consider posting that script if it's not too long.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I finally found what was the problem (I reinstalled libc and it works now). For information, the script was ./chomp 10 10 (testing with 10). I'll remember this great community, great help and great support. Thanks again.

Comment: (is there a way to close the subject?)

Comment: always when you do a program that takes input you need to handle garbage input, your code presumes peachy input and that usually isn't a good idea. a couple of functions to read values from the user and reject invalid values would do wonders for your program as well as not assuming that there is arguments to the program on the command line.

Comment: You say, "Before the `sscanf` there's `if(argc>1 && (strcmp(argv[1],"-h")==0 || strcmp(argv[1],"--help")==0)){...}`", but I don't see that anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(T.tab[i]==NULL){
        printf("Erreur\n");
        exit(1);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        T.tab[i][j]=1;
    }
}
    }
```

You have a `{` and `}` bug. The second `for` loop is inside the first `for` loop and both modifies `i`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I corrected this, but it still gives me segfault at line 5 (?).

Comment: At line 5? Which source file? Is `valgrind` saying line 5?

Comment: When I run it in geany. ./geany_run_script.sh : ligne 5 :  2312 Erreur de segmentation  (core dumped)"./chomp"


------------------
(program exited with code: 139)
Press return to continue

Comment: Your question is incomplete: how is your program called by `./geany_run_script.sh`, what argument are passed?

Comment: The script is "./nameofthebinary".

Comment: If by "The script is "./nameofthebinary" you mean to say that the program is called without any arguments, then the seg fault is where you access argv without first checking argc.

Answer (score 1):

T.tab has a size of `m*n`. Therefore this check is invalid.

```
if((cp->x)<0 || (cp->x)>(pos->T.m) || (cp->y)<0 || (cp->y)>(pos->T.n))
```

Change it to

```
if((cp->x)<0 || (cp->x)>=(pos->T.m) || (cp->y)<0 || (cp->y)>(pos->=T.n))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want the user to choose a case from the tab. So he can't choose more than n or m. He still can choose n or m.

Comment: @user2887595 Your cases of `1...m` and `1...n` should map to `0...m-1` and `0...n-1` in `T.tab` correspondingly.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Tried, still giving me segfault at line 5. And J1 is declared via enum.

Comment: @user2887595 oh sorry